# How to create new button with text based on item in string array?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to create a new button with the text displaying on another form for each item i have in the `Globals.stringItems` string array that I have populated via a .csv text file and displayed with a dataviewgrid.

Here is what I have:

```
Public Class Globals
Public Shared stringItems As String()
End Class

Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

                MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited

                MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {", "}

                Dim currentRow As String()
                'Loop through all of the fields in the file.  
                'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing.  
                While Not MyReader.EndOfData

                    Try
                        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(currentRow)

                        Globals.stringItems = currentRow

                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException

                        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")

                    End Try

                End While

            End Using

        End If

Public Function AddNewButton() As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    For Each item As String In Globals.stringItems
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
        button.Text = ?????????
    Next
    Return button
End Function
```

Am I even close? What am I missing? I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Since `stringItems`  is declared as `Public Shared` it is globally accessed in all functions. so you need not to be specify like  `Globals.stringItems`. and your `AddNewButton()` function is missing some logic.

I observed these from the snippet you have given;

1. You need to create no.of buttons which is equal to the number of items in the string array.
2. If so then you need not to use a Function. sub is enough.

For this scenario you can code like the following:

```
Public Sub AddNewButton()    
    Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100
    For Each item As String In stringItems
        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        button.Location = Location
        button.Text = item
        button.Width=150
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
        buttonTop += 20
    Next
End Function
```

If the `stringItems` contains 7 elements then it creates 7 buttons

Comment: It seems to only produce a button for one item of the array. The CSV file is structured as ITEM1a, ITEM1b and then displayed in a DataViewGrid in 2 columns. I am assuming that the Globals.stringItems = currentRow in my code is adding the rows of the DataViewGrid to items of the Globals.stringItems as string array items. Is my thinking correct? The button produced is simply 1 button, even though there are 5 rows and it only displays ITEM1a as the button text.

Comment: ok. fine. what will be the values in `Globals.stringItem` @ the time of execution of the sub?

Comment: Globals.stringItems should contain everything that is loaded from the CSV file (if my code Globals.stringItems = currentRow is actually adding the values to the Globals.stringItems). It is dynamic so the CSV file can have x amount of entries following the structure of ITEM1a, ITEM1b <newline> ITEM2a, ITEM2b, etc.

Comment: that means `stringItems(0)=" ITEM1a, ITEM1b"  stringItems(1)=" ITEM2a, ITEM2b"` and you have to create 4buttons in this scenario, isn't it?

Comment: No. It would create 2 buttons with the text "ITEM1a, ITEM1b" on button1 and "ITEM2a, ITEM2b" on button2. This assumes that my line of code Globals.stringItems = currentRow is adding the items from the CSV to stringItems as elements in the array properly. I am unsure if that line of code is functioning properly.

Comment: have you tried the code which i had suggested? what it results?

Comment: I have, results are 1 button. The button text is the last line in the csv so, if there are 2 rows, it is displaying ITEM2a as the button text. It is not even displaying the ITEM2a, ITEM2b. Just ITEM2a as text.

Comment: It is now adding the button with ITEM2b insead of ITEM2a as text lol. I beieve the problem is not with your suggestion but my CSV to DataViewGrid to String array code. Namely Globals.stringItems = currentRow. Perhaps I need to work on that code, but i dont see what the problem is there either! lol